# How to promisify a function who doesn't necessary invoke its callback?

Tags: javascript, promise

Consider a function like this:

```
function fetchUser(userId, cb) {
  db.getUserById(userId, function(err, user) {
    if (err)
      return cb(err)
    if (!user)
      return // Pay attention to this line
    return cb(null, user)
  });
}
```

How would you promisify such a function.

Precisely, how would you deal with the simple `return;` statement that doesn't call the callback ?

Should this be a promise that stay in a pending state forever ? Doesn't feel right somehow

Comment: Resolve with nothing?

Comment: Return `null`, if user not found is the normal approach.  Alternatively you could throw an error instead..

Comment: To make life easier, most libs have what's called a promisify function, eg. in node.js it's `util.promisify`,..  you could then just do `const fetchUserPromise = util.promisify(fetchUser)`,  Saves you having to wrap inside a Promise constructor..

Comment: `Should this be a promise that stay in a pending state forever ?` depending on the usecase that might be a good option.